# Некорректно работает перемещение камеры

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Я хочу чтобы камера преследовала игрока и держала его в центре. Я использовал методы cam.translate(), cam.position, cam.lookAt() и передавал в них координаты body игрока отмасштобированные до нужного размера, но каждый раз поведение игры было примерно одним и тем же: сначала отрисовывается tiledMap, затем он перестаёт отрисовываться и остаётся только фон, также не видны коробки всех тел, которые выводятся через box2DDebugRenderer.render(), но остаётся спрайт игрока, а при его движении камера остаётся на месте. Я не понимаю, что я делаю не так и как мне добиться нужного поведения программы.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.
Вот часть моего кода:

```java
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        tiledMapRenderer.setView(cam);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        time += delta;
        frame = ggAnimation.getKeyFrame(time, true);

        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(frame, bodyPers.getPosition().x * PIX_TO_M - WIDTH / 2f,
                bodyPers.getPosition().y * PIX_TO_M - HEIGHT / 2f,
                WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        sb.end();

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
        box2DDebugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined.cpy()
        .scale(PIX_TO_M, PIX_TO_M, 0));
        cam.translate(bodyPers.getPosition().scl(PIX_TO_M));

        cam.update();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему. Я так и не понял, что происходило с отрисовкой карты, но я понял, что я использовал разные системы координат, необходимо было использовать методы  cam.position.set()(почему именно он я так и не разобрался) и sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined) для соответствия систем координат.
Следующий код решает мою проблему:

```
   public void render(float delta) {

      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      tiledMapRenderer.setView(cam);
      tiledMapRenderer.render();

      time += delta;
      frame = ggAnimation.getKeyFrame(time, true);

      sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

      sb.begin();
      sb.draw(frame, bodyPers.getPosition().x * PIX_TO_M - WIDTH / 2f,
              bodyPers.getPosition().y * PIX_TO_M - HEIGHT / 2f,
              WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      sb.end();

      world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

      box2DDebugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined.cpy()
      .scale(PIX_TO_M, PIX_TO_M, 0));

      cam.translate(bodyPers.getPosition().scl(PIX_TO_M));
      cam.position.set(bodyPers.getPosition().x*PIX_TO_M,
              bodyPers.getPosition().y*PIX_TO_M,0);
      cam.update();
  }
```